# Promise.all object map messes the sorting of data

Tags: node.js

I have a node api that returns an object but the object returned are not always at the same order. This is how I did it:

```
const somelist = await Model.find({condition blah blah})
                        .sort({created_at: -1})
                        .select('some fields');
if(!somelist){
    res.status(500).json({ success: false });
}else{
    let arr = [];
    await Promise.all(somelist.map(async (item) => {
        let user = await User.findById(item.some);
        if(user) {
            arr.push(item);
        }
    }));

    console.log(arr)
    res.status(200).json(arr);
}
```

The original display would be 1, 2, 3 but sometimes, it will become 2, 1, 3 but very rarely. Since I added a sort function in my somelist, maybe the issue is in the promise. How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

No, neither `Promise.all` nor `map` does change the oder of an array. `Promise.all` is guaranteed to return the results in the same order as the promisearray, you put in.

**BUT:** the order, in which the promises are resolved isn't guaranteed, thus the `arr.push()` can happen in any order, so you may receive different results. So you can do it somehow like this

```
let arr = (await Promise.all(somelist.map(i => User.findById(i.some)))
  .filter(r => !!r)
```

Assuming that `User.findById()` returns a promise, `somelist.map(...)` returns an array of promises, which you can `await` with `Promise.all`. Once `Promise.all` has resolved, you can `filter` out all elements, which returned a `undefined` or `null` result.

Another possiblity would be the following

```
for (let item of somelist) {
  let u = await User.findById(item.some);
  if (u) arr.push(u);
}
```

But that is serializing your requests and executing one after the other. So this would probably waste a lot of time waiting for some external results (network, database, disk, ...)

Comment: Hmm... I will try this one. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use this code:

```js
   let arr = await Promise.all(somelist.map(async (item) => {
        return await User.findById(item.some);
    }));
```

In your code you push the async function result into an array and this statement not necessarily would work in the specified order. But Promise.all would return resolved results in your original array order.

Comment: I am not an expert in this, but if I return inside, will it return only one item? Since I am returning it inside a map.

Comment: technically your async function in a map call will return a Promise, then Promise.all will wait until all those promises in the array would be resolved and finally as a result of await the Promise.all would return the array of results of resolved promises in the same order as an original array